# cant figure out why my discord bot isnt returning correct status of server

Tags: python, sockets, server, discord.py, bots

here is the code i have come up with.
it runs and sends the message "server offline" but its not offline.
ive tried to use ping command as well and that didnt seem to work either.
wondering if maybe im missing a library to run these functions or a bit of code thatll do the trick or if its just the server denying my pings and my socket connection.
im able to ping it using other methods so i dont think this is the case.
at one point i got it to show online but when it went offline it didnt send a notification and i cant figure out what i did to make that happen.

```
import os
import discord
import socket
import asyncio

TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']

CHANNEL_ID = 1170961716901855262

SERVER_IP = '5.62.122.45'
SERVER_PORT = 7783

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def check_server_status():
    prev_status = None

    while True:
        # Attempt to create a socket to the server on the specified port
        try:
            await client.wait_until_ready()
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.settimeout(5)
                s.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
                current_status = "online"
        except (socket.timeout, ConnectionRefusedError):
            current_status = "offline"

        if current_status != prev_status:
            prev_status = current_status
            channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)

            await channel.send(f"Server is now {current_status}")

        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Check the server status every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    client.loop.create_task(check_server_status())

client.run(TOKEN)
```

ive tried other ip address's and ports and they were all coming back offline. im using replit so idk if maybe thats the reason?

Comment: What is running on the port you‘re trying to connect to?

Comment: Probably a replit issue. Guessing it has external connections blocked/some sort of weird firewall. Try replicate this bot on your local machine and see if it works. then you will have your answer